# .htacces to capture the page name and send it as a get method

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to capture a url such as

```
http://www.mysite.com/somepage.php?sometext=somevalue
```

and redirect it to.

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=somepage.php&sometext=somevalue
```

I tried searching for such .htaccess online, but couldn't find it.

Can you please help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I structure my query string in MVC htaccess applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516883/how-should-i-structure-my-query-string-in-mvc-htaccess-applications)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite sure this is a duplicate, <del>but I'm having a bit of an issue finding it/them</del> [Edit: [I found one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516883/how-should-i-structure-my-query-string-in-mvc-htaccess-applications), though possibly not the best example].

Anyway, this is a fairly standard problem resolved with fairly standard code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The `RewriteRule` captures the entire request as `$1`, and passes it to index.php as the `page` GET parameter.

The `[QSA]` flag on the end says to take any existing GET parameters (`sometext=somevalue` in your example), and add them as additional GET parameters on the new request. (The `[L]` flag just says that this should be the last rule executed.)

Note that this will also redirect requests for things like images or CSS files, so it's good to add the following lines *directly before* this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

These lines say "if the request is for a file or directory that actually exists, don't process the rule." That way, requests for real files will be served directly by Apache, rather than being handled (or more likely, mishandled) by your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php?sometext=(.*)$ index.php?page=$1.php&sometext=$2 [QSA,L] #rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*).php?sometext=(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=$1.php&sometext=$2 [R=301,L] #redirect
```